# Is every unitary representation a direct sum of irreducible subprepresentations?

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

I've read that any unitary representation of a compact group decomposes as a Hilbert space direct sum of irreducible representations. In the book I'm reading this is stated as a prong of the Peter-Weyl theorem.  It seems to me that this should just be a straighforward application of Zorn's lemma and trans finite induction since the intersection of a nested sequence of closed invariant subspaces is again closed and invariant (edit: it just occurred to me that this intersection may be trivial).  This doesn't seem to use compactness of G. Is this right or am I missing something? If such an argument doesn't work, can I derive this fact for compact G from the other parts of the Peter Weyl theorem, namely that $L^2(G)$ is a Hilbert space direct sum of the irreducible unitary representations of G (which are finite dimensional)?

Comment: @PeterFranek But all the representations are unitary, so the inner product is G invariant?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I deleted my comment.

Comment: But it still can happen that an infinite intersection of invariant closed subspaces is $0$, but any finite intersection is an infinite dimensional (not irreducible) invariant subspace, not?

Comment: if $(\mathbb R,+)$ acts on $L^2(\mathbb R)$ via $(a.f)(x)=f(x-a)$ ($a\in\mathbb R,f\in L^2$) then there are no irreducible sub-representations.

Comment: @user8268 interesting! Thanks very much.  Any thoughts on how to get the result for compact groups from the Peter Weyl theorem?

Comment: (user8268:except constants)

Comment: @PeterFranek yes! You're right. Thank you for your help. Any thoughts on the second question?

Comment: @PeterFranek constants are not a subspace in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ (oh those definitions)

Comment: Right. I don't have a good day today, I will rather start thinking about math in the morning :)